# Entity Framework 5 will not add Item to Collection, how to fix this?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-5

So I have a this model https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHgQz.png , and I would like create a Update with a Program, so I first create the update, fill in all the neccesary items, find a MachineType and maybe a program, but if none is found, get the first program from the MachineType.
Note: All MachineTypes have at least 1 program.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvInput.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvInput.Rows[i];
            int machineTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
            Update update = new Update();
            update.MachineType.Add(Check.prombase.MachineTypes.First(mt => mt.MachineTypeId == machineTypeId));
            foreach (Program program in database.Programs)
            {
                if (program.ProgramVersion.Split('v')[0] == row.Cells[5].Value.ToString())
                {   //If a program is added here, it will save it
                    update.Program.Add(program);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (update.Program.Count == 0)
                foreach (Program program in database.Programs)
                {   //When a program is added here, it will NOT save it
                    if (program.MachineType.MachineTypeId == machineTypeId)
                    {
                        update.Program.Add(program);
                        break; //When debugging it comes here everytime
                    }
                }
            //Here it is always: update.Program.Count = 1
            database.AddToUpdates(update);
            database.SaveChanges();

            if (update.MachineType.Count == 0 || update.Program.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("This error is nevers shown!");
        }
```

The problem is, it always says it has a program but in reality it is not.
What am I doing wrong that it wont add a Program to my Update?

edit VARAK:
After replacing the code it still won't save it, also added this at the end

```
reloadDatabase();

foreach(Update update in database.Updates)
    if (update.Program.Count == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("This can't be happening");
```

Comment: So you're saying the data is not persisted - did you check that with SQL-Manager or similar?

Comment: I checked it with my application to manage the items, when loading it with a Foreach Program prog in the Update it tells me it contains no Programs.

Comment: We don't know your display logic - so i ask again: what says SQL-Manager?

Normally there three reasons for not adding data: 1) Object-Graphs are not added (so every entity has to be added by yourself) or 2) Theres an exception or 3) Theres a problem with your keys

Comment: 1. I'm sorry but I do not understand how to view the Many-To-Many items in a SQL(CE) Database, I used CompactView and the Build in in Visual Studio. 
2. It does not throw a exception of any kind.
3. It does have the associations added in the Entity Framework if that is what you mean.
Sorry I'm still learning so my answers/question might look retarded for you guys.

Comment: Many-to-Many-Relationships are translated into a table which is probalby called Update_MachineType or Program_MachineType or Update_Program (or any other combination of them), but if you used Model-First, then the keys will (probably) be okay.
Can you show us your model?

Comment: The strange thing is that it will add & save a Program in the first foreach but not in the second while it does add it http://i.imgur.com/tz8ZVPT.png, also my apology since the only M2M is Update_MachineType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, as you can see in my model the Program can have 1 Update, so when a new Update gets created the with the same Program as another Update, that other Update will lose the Program connected.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvInput.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgvInput.Rows[i];
        int machineTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value);
        Update update = new Update();
        update.MachineType.Add(Check.prombase.MachineTypes.First(mt => mt.MachineTypeId == machineTypeId));

        var programVal = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "v";

        var program = database.Programs.FirstOrDefault(prog => prog.ProgramVersion.StartsWith(programVal));

        if (program == null)
            program = database.Programs.First(prog => prog.MachineType.MachineTypeId == machineTypeId);

        update.Program.Add(program);            

        database.AddToUpdates(update);
        database.SaveChanges();

        //This will never show an error as the update that you are accessing here is the one you created in memory (Not the one in the DB)
        if (update.MachineType.Count == 0 || update.Program.Count == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("This will never show!");

        //To get the error, pull the update from the database again
        var updateNew = database.Updates.First(upd => upd.UpdateId == update.UpdateId);
        if (updateNew.MachineType.Count == 0 || updateNew.Program.Count == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("This will show if prog was not saved");

    }
```

This code should be more efficient and might shed a bit more light if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, really appreciate it, but for some reason it still won't save it, I edited the question with a piece of code I added, but it still wont save the program from the .First().
It also triggers MessageBox.Show("This can't be happening");

Comment: Does the "This will show if prog was not saved" error message fire?

Comment: No, it does not. But I after a reload it does.